# приложение написаное в среде linux будет ли оно работать в Windows если я упакую его в Docker?

Tags: python, linux, windows, docker

Возник вопрос будет ли работать приложение если я писал его под linux но запускаю с docker контейнера на windows??

Comment: Вся суть docker - это переносимость. Да, будет.

Comment: @dmtr, абсолютно нет. Это такой же эффект, как для понижения температуры люди пьют *обезболивающее* под названием аспирин.

Comment: @0andriy какие могут быть проблемы, если запускать контейнер без необходимости дергать ресурсы самого хоста?

Answer (score 0):

Докер - это только контейнер, работающий поверх базовой системы, а не полноценная виртуальная машина. Соответственно в общем случае докер сам по себе не делает приложения переносимыми. Причем это относится не только к переносу на совершенно другую систему, но и к переносу на другой вариант линукса, или даже на тот же вариант линукса, но с другими настройками.

Comment: Извините, а есть примеры, когда контейнер докера не работает на другом варианте линукса (видимо, имеется в виду другой дистрибутив)?

Comment: @art-solopov Докер контейнеры используют ядро (kernel) и хоста. Соответственно работоспособность контейнеров напрямую определяется совместимостью ядер. Особенно если приложение само делает системные вызовы. Также на практике это выливается в то, что любые компоненты режима ядра помещать в контейнер в принципе не выйдет. Например для работы с cuda [придется ставить драйвер на хосте](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA). Пример попроще - для многих видов диагностики и профилирования желательно иметь снятый флажок kptr_restrict - его придется задавать на хосте.